# SQL LIKE (Reverse)

Tags: sql

I'm kinda confused on how this thing can be done. 
I have a database table having these values:

```
| id |  file_type | code | position |
-------------------------------------
| 1  |    Order   |  SO  |   1      |
| 2  |    Order   | 1-SO |   7      |
| 3  |    Order   | 1_SO |   7      |
```

Now, I want to get the position and the file type of my filename so I come up with this query:

```
SET @FileName = '1-SO1234567890.pdf'

SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_FileTypes 
WHERE  CHARINDEX(code,@FileName)> 0
```

Sadly, I'm getting two results here, I only need the data with the "1-SO" result.

```
| id |  file_type | code | position |
-------------------------------------
| 1  |    Order   |  SO  |   1      |
| 2  |    Order   | 1-SO |   7      |
```

I believe that my WHERE Clause causes this to happen.
Is there any better way for me to get my desired results?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Am I grossly misunderstanding something, or should this be `SET @FileName = '1-SO1234567890.pdf'`?

Comment: oops! my bad, I corrected it now. Thank you LittleBobbyTables.

Comment: Are you testing that it `StartsWith` the code, or should it be the longest matching code, or something else? Basically, it's unclear why `1-SO` is a better match than `SO` - please clarify.

Comment: "you get what you select" confucius

Comment: well..your code is working as designed. `SO` and `1-SO`.both satisfy the `WHERE` vlause

Comment: Also, how are IDs 2 or 3 any different?  And are you supposed to use the `position` column for anything?  Your examples really aren't clear.

Comment: does file name always start with code ie you never have a file names like '9-BB67SO678.pdf'

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: 3 includes an underscore (`_`), not a minus/hyphen (`-`).

Comment: @MarkBannister - thanks, I must have looked at that a dozen times and couldn't tell the difference.  Time for new glasses...

Comment: Hi RB, I have filenames with SO12323232.pdf, 1-SO1233232.pdf, 1_SO1233232.pdf. and the position column is used for substring purposes. I have this query inside a stored procedure

Comment: Yes - but why is "1-SOxxx" a better match than "SOxxx"?

Comment: It's the format that was given to us. I know SOxxx is better, but we have to match the exact code from the filename. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `SUBSTRING` instead (assuming T-SQL):

```
WHERE code = SUBSTRING(@FileName,1, LEN(code));
```

Which checks if the first n-chars of `FileName` equal a given `code`.

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02631b/11/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This thing works! More power to you Tim Schmelter. :)

Comment: Note same problem as my solution though. If you have two codes 1-SO 1_S, this will return both if the file is '1-SO.....'

Answer (score 0):

well

```
SET @FileName = '1-SO1234567890.pdf'

SELECT * 
FROM   tbl_FileTypes 
WHERE  CHARINDEX(code,@FileName) = 1
```

would work in this case but if you had a code '1-SOS' it's going to fail again.

Comment: I was over the 10k then the user that gave me the points got removed. Not fair :( :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you are `cheking left most characters`, you could also use `LEFT()` function as below. Also use `TOP (1)` to get a single record and consider ordering as needed.

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM   tbl_FileTypes 
WHERE  LEFT(@FileName,LEN(code)) = code
--ORDER BY yourCol
```